# Jquery loaded content, doesn't work with other scripts

Tags: jquery, scripting, refresh

I'm a beginner jquery user so I'm really hoping this will be quite straight forward for someone with a bit of experience. I recently implemented a jquery script that loads the content for a div from another html page. This works beautifully and I'm really happy with the result. The problem I'm now having is that my Lytebox and Flexcroll scripts won't work on the loaded content. Below is the load content script. I thought I could just add

```
fleXenv.initByClass("flexcroll"); 
initLytebox();
```

to the end of the script. This doesnt work when the content is loaded the first time. But if I click a dead link in the page and it runs this script again then the Lytebox and Flexcroll scripts kick in. I basically need to know when and how to refresh the Lytebox and Flexcroll scripts

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#nav li a').click(function(){  

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';  
$('#content').fadeOut('400',loadContent);  
$('#load').remove();  
$('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
$('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
function loadContent() {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()); 
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content').fadeIn('400',hideLoader());  
}   
function hideLoader() {  
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
}  
return false;  
}); 


});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am currently at the bottom of a 3day pit of dispair. Dreamweaver is making a fool of me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sussed it! For anyone who is suffering with this as I have for the last 3 days. Here is my fix:

I created a new script in the html header:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){     
// fire when any Ajax requests complete })
```

And then told all scripts to initialise within this script.

Comment: What happens if the loaded HTML Page does ajax requests? Is _ajaxComplete_ called, this may lead to some issues if not handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they are clashing because of using the same selectors.  This can also happen when the script reference order is incorrect in the head of your page.

Try using the JQuery noconflict method;

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

If that does not work then override the $ function.  Instructions are here;

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think I understand the logic but I'm having difficulty implementing it. I've tried to add 

var j = jQuery.noConflict(); to the start of the script and replace the $ thereafter

I've also tried adding $.noConflict(); before the 'return false' and then the init other scripts after the no conflict.

Still no luck

Comment: Right, I've been doing some serious reading and I'm convinced this is my problem. I have tried to implement the noConflict but I'm clearly too much of an amateur to do this correctly without a detailed guide. So I thought maybe I could over come this by replacing all the $ symbols for 'jquery' as my script is really small but it seems it just wont run the script at all, when I do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I have managed to impliment the noConflict jQuery. And it seems that this is not the problem. I need to write a line of code so that when the new content is loaded immediately after it reloads the other scripts on the site. Please could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add these to the end of the script, because the loading happens *asynchronously*. In other words, by the time your `click` function returns, nothing has been loaded yet; this happens in the background, and your callback function `showNewContent` is called after it's done.

I'm guessing that you'd want to do the initialization in that function as well:

```
function showNewContent() {  
    fleXenv.initByClass("flexcroll");
    initLytebox();
    $('#content').fadeIn('400',hideLoader());  
}
```

---

Also, instead of this:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
```

write this:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
```

Instead of calling the `showNewContent` function and passing its result to the `load` function, you want to pass *the `showNewContent` function itself* to `load`. You can do this because, in JavaScript, everything is an object.

The same thing goes for `hideLoader`.

---

Also also, I think there's a space too many inside the quotes here:

```
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Thomas, I've amended my code to but its still not playing game. What does this mean?